# Rotating a triangle image from the center using CSS only?

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms

I'm trying to rotate a triangle image from the center using CSS.

I can rotate the image but it is not rotating from the middle.

This is what I have so far:

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#loading {
  animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="loading" src='https://i.postimg.cc/zVSqhnr9/loader.png' border='0' alt='loader' />
```

This seems to have some effect on its position but I cants get it right:

```
transform-origin: 30% 80%;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an equilateral triangle so the center is not the center of the image, you should adjust the `transform-origin` like this.

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#loading {
  animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
  transform-origin: calc(100% / 2) calc(100% * 2 / 3);
  /* transform-origin: 50%  66.666% */
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="loading" src='https://i.postimg.cc/zVSqhnr9/loader.png' border='0' alt='loader' />
```

[image]

For the calculation details we have the following equations:

```
a² + c² = b²
c  + b  = Height
a² + Height² = (2a)²
2a = Width
```

After solving we will obtain:

```
a = 1/2 * Width   (50%)
b = 2/3 * Height  (66.666%)
c = 1/3 * Height
```

Comment: @JamesJuanjie it's exactly 2/3 * 100 :)

Answer (score 1):

To get the center of your triangle:

**(90, 158/3)**

Then, subtract **(158/3)** to **158** to get the Y coordinate from the top, instead of the bottom.

---

[image]

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#loading {
  transform-origin: 90px 105.3px;
  animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="loading" src='https://i.postimg.cc/zVSqhnr9/loader.png' border='0' alt='loader'/>
```

Comment: more precisely it's 2/3*158 ;)

Comment: IE10, IE11, and Edge < 14 don't support using calc() inside a transform. [source](https://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

Comment: I know, I used calc to show the calculation, then you can easily change it with 66.666% ;) .. and I didn't use it inside transform, but transform-origin